Frameworks comparison for Object Detection (Pytorch)
I'm trying to compare or choose a framework for object detection, meanwhile, I found two:
MMDetection + MMYOlo
Detectorn2
If someone have experience with above, please share pros and cons.
Or if there are some other framework suggestion lmk.

hey, this is really not a question with an objectively quantifiably correct answer, but more a request for opinions, personal experiences and discussions – these are off-topic here. (see "what should I avoid asking" in the help pages.)

For object detection I'd use YOLO v8 by Ultralytics.
It has a simple training phase with built in data augmentation and learning rate scheduling.
The small models are highly efficient and can used in edge devices.
The larger models are very capable.
I'd use it before the other 2 you mentioned, which in my opinion, are bloated in comparison.

https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmyolo is different for mUltralytics framework ?

@MichaelD, What do you mean?

I meant that https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmyolo is probably similar to Ultralytics framework. Can you address differences between them ?

@MichaelD, I don't have experience with it. It seems to be a "copy paste" project which just throws in other models.
